# Difference between Chromatic Number and Clique Number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be any graph with $|V|=n$ vertices.

It is known that $\chi \ge \omega$, where $\chi$ (resp., $\omega$) is the *chromatic* (resp., *clique*) number of $G$.

There are several examples (e.g., [the Mycielskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian)) that show that $\chi - \omega$ can be made arbitrarily large. However, in all such examples this difference seems to grow very slowly (i.e., logarithmically) with the number of vertices $n$.

Is this is always the case? Are there graphs for which the difference between the chromatic number and the clique number can be made, say, of the order $n^a$, for some $a>0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes; in fact, for most graphs, the difference is very large.

Consider the random graph on $n$ vertices: for every edge, we flip an independent fair coin to determine if that edge is present or not.

Then for large $n$, the clique number is almost always close to $2\log_2 n$. Proving that it is actually often this high is tricky, so I'll just prove that it usually does not go higher.

The probability that a set of $k$ vertices forms a clique is $2^{-\binom k2}$, and there are $\binom nk$ sets of $k$ vertices, so the expected number of cliques of order $k$ is $\binom nk 2^{-\binom k2}$, which is very approximately $n^k 2^{-k^2/2}$. When we set $k = 2\log_2 n$, $n^k 2^{-k^2/2} = 1$, and the actual expected number of cliques (without the approximation) is going to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This means that the probability of having even a single clique on more than $2\log_2 n$ vertices is also going to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Meanwhile, there is a different obstacle to having a small chromatic number: the inequality $\chi(G) \ge \frac{n}{\alpha(G)}$, where $\alpha(G)$ is the independence number of $G$. By the same argument as for cliques, the largest independent set in $G$ (the largest set of vertices with no edges between them) also almost never exceeds $2 \log_2 n$. Well, in a proper coloring of $G$, every color must induce an independent set. Therefore for almost all $G$, no color has more than $2\log_2 n$ vertices, and therefore at least $\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}$ colors are needed.

(This is actually a good estimate of the chromatic number of the random graph but, again, the reverse bound is very hard to prove; it was shown by Bollobás in 1988.)

So with probability close to $1$ for a random graph, and therefore for almost all $n$-vertex graphs, the clique number and chromatic number are very far apart: the former is less than $2\log_2 n$ and the latter is more than $\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}$.

Comment: Wow, this was a very clear answer, thank you so much! Do you have any idea if the same holds for second power graphs $G^2$ (in which two vertices are adjacent iff their distance in $G$ is at most $2$)? I was actually dealing with them when I found myself wondering the question I posted. Since they have a particular structure I don't see as clearly if they would be included in the almost all $n$-vertex graphs in which clique and chromatic number are far apart.

Comment: Graphs $G$ whose square $G^2$ has very different $\chi$ and $\omega$ are less common, but do exist. For example, based on the paper [The chromatic number of graph powers](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/combinatorics-probability-and-computing/article/chromatic-number-of-graph-powers/EE472080B2429D0C5B3EC621A13727A0) by Alon and Mohar, for all $d$ there are graphs $G$ with girth $g \ge 7$ and maximum degree $d$ such that $\chi(G^2)= \Theta(\frac{d^2}{\log d})$; but $\omega(G^2)$ is bounded by $d+1$ for such graphs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the excellent reference. Very much appreciated! How do you see that $\omega(G^2)\le d+1$ for graphs with girth $g\ge 7$ and maximum degree $d$? In the paper I could only find that $\omega(G^2) \le d^2-d+1$ when the girth is $6$.

Comment: Take any three vertices $u,v,w$ in a clique in $G^2$. Then there is a $u,v$-path, a $v,w$-path, and a $w,u$-path in $G$ of length $\le2$, which combine to a closed walk of length $\le6$. This is a degenerate closed walk ($G$ has girth $\ge7$) so either one of $u,v,w$ lies on the path between the other two and the walk is something like $u,v,w,v,u$, or $u,v,w$ are all adjacent to a third vertex $x$ and the walk is $u,x,v,x,w,x,u$. Thus, we can't have vertices in a clique in $G^2$ that aren't all adjacent to the same vertex in $G$: each clique consists of $x$ plus its $\le d$ neighbors in $G$.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!